# Workflow approval status change errors out

Tags: workflow, netsuite

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJxQh.jpg)My workflow which was working well so far has suddenly started giving me error related to approval status, the error message is

'Invalid approvalstatus reference key 11'

I am trying to use the Set Field Value property on the ‘Approval Status’ as normal and I have no idea why it has suddenly started erroring out.

Answer (score 0):

The Approval Status 11 may not exist or is Inactive

Comment: This is repeating the question differently. Obviously the error message quoted means the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Check which is the approvalstatus id 11 and verify if it is still active or a valid status. This could have already been inactivated or deleted from the system.